# Override file in node_modules lib using webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I have a `react` + `typescript` + `nextjs` project structure. It has 2 different projects, one is a utility library which is reusable across all the frontend project. I am using that utility library in my `react` + `typescript` + `NextJS` project as a dependency (added in `package.json`). The utility library has one default authentication function to check roles and permissions, and those roles and permissions differ for every other frontend project.

Is there any way where I can override those authentication functions using webpack based on the frontend project (I can use environment variable to differentiate)?

Comment: Do you have webpack configuration for each project?

Comment: Can you add a sample code of the authentication function and imported locations please?

Comment: @RazRonen Yes, each project will be seperate and their separate webpack config

Comment: You can create a custom plugin the hook the buildModule hook and override the function, this plugin will get the override function in its constructor. Will this solution suits you?